# Seeking MOOCs (online training courses) for remote sensing?

Tags: remote-sensing, references, training

I'm looking for a MOOC (Massive Open Online Course) for remote sensing.

Does anyone know if there is currently running or if is there  any change to begin in the future any MOOC for remote sensing?

Answer (score 3):

> This question has been converted to Community Wiki and wiki locked
>   because it is an example of a question that seeks a list of answers
>   and appears to be popular enough to protect it from closure.  It
>   should be treated as a special case and should not be viewed as the
>   type of question that is encouraged on this, or any Stack Exchange
>   site, but if you wish to contribute more content to it then feel free
>   to do so by editing this answer.

---

There isn't much out there in terms of MOOCs for remote sensing. The most recent offering i have come across was from [The European Space Agency - Monitoring Climate from Space](https://www.futurelearn.com/courses/climate-from-space). The next session of this MOOC starts on the 25th of July 2016.

- Week 1 - Observing Climate Change from Space

What is Earth observation? How do we observe the Earth with satellites? And what role does Earth observation play in climate policy and planning?

- Weeks 2 & 3 - Earth Observation Techniques and Technology

How do we use different types of mission, instrumentation and data to study changes to our atmosphere, land, oceans and ice?

- Week 4 - Earth Observation in Action

How does Earth observation help us set policy; plan for climate risk, resilience and adaptation; and manage resources and biodiversity?

- Week 5 - Managing Earth Observation Data

How do we make sense of the large amount of data produced by Earth observation? Can crowdsourcing and citizen science play a role in developing climate change models?

**If you are looking for a technical how-to guide, consult your software documentation.**

For an introduction to remote sensing, check out [this tutorial](http://fas.org/irp/imint/docs/rst/Front/tofc.html) from NASA, amongst others. There are several options out there.

---

I would recommend the fourth Course "Imagery, Automation, and Applications" in the excellent GIS Specialization provided by the University of California, Davis on Coursera.

The course teaches remotely sensed and satellite imagery, introduces the electromagnetic spectrum, and trains students on using GIS software to process and analyze Satellite imagery.

Link to the GIS specialization: https://www.coursera.org/specializations/gis

Link to the fourth course: https://www.coursera.org/learn/gis-applications

---

I have compiled some lists of free GIS and Remote Sensing courses around including the GIS specialization listed above.

GIS Related Courses on Coursera: https://www.justspatial.com/gis-moocs-free-courses-coursera/

GIS and RS Related Courses on Edx: https://www.justspatial.com/gis-remote-sensing-free-courses/

Remote Sensing courses on BRS Lab: https://www.justspatial.com/free-remote-sensing-courses-by-brs/

---

You can visit GEO University, an online platform containing self-paced courses related to earth observation, remote sensing and GIS.

All available courses are here: https://www.geo.university/